# Stack Overflow formatting problems

Tags: support, stack-overflow, markdown

When I visit the stackoverflow.com home page everything seems to work correctly. In particular:

1. when I use the mouse to hover over my userid on the top line of the page a popup  showing reputation activity over the last day is displayed
2. My two favourite tags, "Java" and "Swing" are displayed
3. the "Java" questions are highlighted with the orangey background

However, when I click on the "Java" favourite tag to filter the questions I notice some problems:

1. hovering over my userid on the top line of the page no longer displays the "reputation popup".
2. tags related to "Swing" are not highlighted with the orangey background color

Additionally, when I look at a question that includes posted code, the code is not formatted. That is the code is displayed in a separate text area, but all the code is left justified. The code indentation is missing. This is the biggest problem for me as I find reading unformatted code to be very confusing.

Note, I just returned to using Stack Overflow 5 days ago and the site was working correctly. It has only been the last 2 or 3 days that these problems started happening.

I use IE 9 on Windows 7.

I have closed all IE windows and deleted all files from the cache to make sure I am picking up the most recent JS files.

Any ideas on what could be causing this or how to fix this?

Edit:

Here is how I see code that is included with a question:

[image]

Comment: I think some screenshots would help here.

Comment: I seem to remember there was some issue with IE and compatibility mode. Check whether that's turned on, and if so, turn it off?

Comment: @DanielFischer, thanks so much that did the job. I must have clicked on the icon by mistake.

Comment: I use firefox, and have encountered no problems whatsoever. Have you tried another browser?

Comment: I am in firefox and I am having this same problem.  I get the verbiage on the page, but there is no formatting.  And I cannot add any comments.  Everything was fine earlier today.  What can I do to get the formatting back?